# how to read data from the BNO085 sensor

Tags: i2c, serial-communication, sensor-fusion, imu, mcu

How to read and write the data in the BNO085 sensor through I2C.
I2C interface is available sensor but no register data are available in datasheet.

Comment: BNO080 or BNO085?

Answer (score 0):

It has something called a 'sensor-hub' and you can use SH2 specific commands, which are written through the I2C to configure BNO and get data. For instance, writing the following through I2C will configure BNO to stream orientation as 'ARVR-Stabilized Rotation Vector (0x28)' at 50
Hz (20us = 0x4e20).

```
CARGO_NO++;
START_BNO_ALGO[21] = {0x15, 0x00, 0x02, CARGO_NO,   0xFD, 0x28,   0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   0x20, 0x4e,    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

I2C_Write(BNO085_ADDRESS, START_BNO_ALGO, 21);
```

Then you can simply I2C_Read the BNO at 50Hz (ideally at BNO interrupt) to get orientation. Hope this will help you to get started.
Please check the 'SH-2 Reference Manual' and the 'Sensor Hub Transport Protocol' for more details.