# How to interface with BNO085 using Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: c, embedded, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to read sensor data (BNO085) from my raspberry pi pico w using the C/C++ SDK (Circuit Python isn't feasible because of timing constraints).I am using I2C.

I've written a basic C program to try and read raw data but the output does not make much sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/i2c.h"
#include "pico/binary_info.h"

// Define the I2C instance and pins for Pico W
#define I2C_PORT i2c0
#define SDA_PIN 4
#define SCL_PIN 5

static int bno_addr = 0x4A;

// Main function
int main() {
    // Initialize stdio for output
    stdio_init_all();
    sleep_ms(2000); // Wait a bit for USB serial connection to establish


    // Initialize I2C (open-flush)
    i2c_init(I2C_PORT, 100 * 1000); // Initialize at 100kHz
    gpio_set_function(SDA_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_set_function(SCL_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_pull_up(SDA_PIN);
    gpio_pull_up(SCL_PIN);



   uint8_t send_product_ID[2] = {0xF9, 0x00};
   printf("%d\n", i2c_write_blocking(I2C_PORT, bno_addr, send_product_ID, sizeof(send_product_ID),   false));
   sleep_ms(100);

   uint8_t recieveArrp[16];
   printf("%d\n", i2c_read_blocking(I2C_PORT, bno_addr, recieveArrp, 16, true));
   for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("\n%02x", recieveArrp[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
2
16

14
01
00
00
00
01
04
00
00
00
00
80
06
31
2e
30
```

It appears to be sending and receiving data correctly, but the actual result does not make sense, as
the first byte should be the report ID 0XF8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have omitted the four byte SHTP header which must proceed the Report ID request as defined in section 1.3 of the [datasheet](https://www.ceva-ip.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/BNO080_085-Datasheet.pdf).

The datasheet makes reference to the following references for further detail:

1. [1000-3625 – SH-2 Reference Manual, CEVA.](https://www.ceva-ip.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/SH-2-Reference-Manual.pdf)
2. [1000-3535 – Sensor Hub Transfer Protocol, CEVA.](https://www.ceva-ip.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Sensor-Hub-Transport-Protocol.pdf)

The answer at the  related
[how to read data from the BNO085 sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253384/how-to-read-data-from-the-bno085-sensor) shows the use of the header.